# CSS font-face support in Internet Explorer 7 only

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, font-face

I have downloaded this free font kit from http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Chantelli-Antiqua
and I can see it properly in any common browser (including the old IE6) but in IE7. I just downloaded the kit and opened the demo file in any browser I have installed but IE7 looks like having some problem with it. Is it an IE issue or CSS? Thanks!

CSS code:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'ChantelliAntiquaRegular';
src: url('Chantelli_Antiqua-webfont.eot');
src: url('Chantelli_Antiqua-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('Chantelli_Antiqua-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('Chantelli_Antiqua-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('Chantelli_Antiqua-webfont.svg#ChantelliAntiquaRegular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

Comment: Very strange ... looks good to me! Are you sure that when viewing in IE7 it's not going into 'quirks mode'?

Comment: How could I check that, how could I prevent it? Thanks!

Comment: if you go into IE9 (or 10 in desktop mode) and press F12 you should see a bar at the bottom appear with two dropdowns in it (browser mode and document mode), make sure both are set to IE7 (hope this makes sense)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace `format('embedded-opentype')` with `format('eot')` - should help.